# tweepy: tweets full_text includes tweets picture link too

Tags: python, url, twitter, tweepy

the title says everything but i'll explain it here too.
i am getting tweets out of tweeter using tweepy (python)
when i get full_text of a tweet type of media, tweepy add the picture link automatically to the end of the text.
but i'm already getting the picture link using code below and i don't want the link in my full_text

```
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                   q=query,
                   lang="fa",
                   tweet_mode='extended',
                   include_entities=True,
                   ).items()

for tweet in tweets:
    if "media" in tweet.entities:
        if tweet.entities['media'][0]['type'] == "photo":
            print(tweet.full_text)
```

how can i get rid of it in some tweepy way or should i use other ways and modules to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for others with this problem just do this:

```
tweet_text = tweet.full_text
tweet_media = tweet.entities['media'][0]['url']
tweet_text = tweet_text.replace(tweet_media, '')
```